# Force www for TYPO3 backend

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

The .htaccess for a TYPO3 6.2 site has those two URL rewriting blocks (among others)

```
# Regular TYPO3 / RealURL rewrites
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^typo3$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^typo3/.*$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php

# force www for frontend to avoid duplicate content
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

How can I force the www for the backend (`/typo3`, `/typo3/`, `typo3/index.php`) as well?

I've tried things like `RewriteRule ^typo3(.*)?$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/typo3/$1 [R=301,L]` but only got errors.

- The reason why I want do do this: there are JS errors in RTE which
  result in reduced functionality (can't create links).
- The reason for these erros: cross-domain policy.
- And the cause for this: the "anti duplicate content" rule above - strangely, rewriting doesn't stop stop at `^typo3$`.

So maybe I don't even need to force www, but clarify why the rewriting doesn't stop where it should.

Not sure if related: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/65705

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reorder your rules like this:

```
# Regular TYPO3 / RealURL rewrites
RewriteEngine On

# force www for frontend to avoid duplicate content
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteRule ^typo3(/.*)?$ - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```